# Making Mapbox annotations have different images depending on a variable?

Tags: swift, annotations, uikit, uiimage, mapbox

So I'm creating my annotations in a for loop as follows in the update map view function:

```
for item in array {
    let latitude = item.latitude
    let longitude = item.longitude
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let annotation = //make an annotation that uses a different image in Assets depending on a variable called "imageID"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

I tried using reuseIdentifiers but wasn't even getting close to figuring this out. I also tried using the imageFor function and making a custom annotation class (to detect what the image passed in was and change the view accordingly) but it didn't work:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    var image: UIImage?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}

func mapView( _ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation ) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
        
    let annotationImage: MGLAnnotationImage
    let annotationImageToilet = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "custom1")
    let annotationImageDefault = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "defaultImage")
            
    switch annotation.image { //tried to sort according to the image value of the custom class
        case "custom1":
            var featureAnnotation = FeatureAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, title: "Title", subtitle: "subtitle")
            featureAnnotation.image = UIImage(named: "custom1")!
            annotationImage = annotationImageToilet ?? featureAnnotation //couldn't get this line working properly
        default:
            var featureAnnotation = FeatureAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, title: "Title", subtitle: "subtitle")
            featureAnnotation.image = UIImage(named: "defaultImage")!
            annotationImage = annotationImageDefault ?? featureAnnotation //couldn't get this line working properly
        }
            
        return annotationImage
 }
```

Essentially, I just want the image of the custom annotations to change depending on what feature.imageID is, any help much appreciated!

Comment: What about this has to do with SwiftUI?

Comment: @jnpdx Well, for example this is UIKit-based: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/    --- and my app is SwiftUI based so solutions involving UIKit won't be helpful and I just wanted to make that clear, is that okay?

Comment: You have not included any SwiftUI code in your question and it's not clear why it would be relevant to the question. MGLMapView and UIImage are based on UIKit. If there's a relevant SwiftUI component to it, you may want to add that to your question.

Comment: @jnpdx You know what, you're 100% right, I meant UIKit, not SwiftUI